# GAS openByUrl() error: invalid argument: url

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-docs

Why does this code:

```
var target = createDuplicateDocument(template, docName);
var targetDocId = target.getId();
var link = target.getUrl();
var myVariable = DocumentApp.openByUrl(newDocLink).getText();
```

produce this error?

```
14-02-01 11:02:37:973 BRST] DocumentApp.openByUrl([https://docs.google.com/open?id=1kQWDgh7Qe80pCuvs2VQjPhJGCSk9KXXXs4Nqt2pLH1c]) [0 segundos]
[14-02-01 11:02:38:931 BRST] Falha na execução: Argumento inválido: url (line 238, file "mainScript") [2.796 segundos de tempo de execução total]
```

I also tried   `var myVariable = DocumentApp.openByUrl(newDocLink[0]).getText();` and it didn't work.  I know I could use `openById`, but I want get `openByUrl` working. Thanks!

Comment: line 238 is mentioned in the error. Can you post what is on and around line 238?

Comment: Thanks, @wruckie. Line 238 is this line `var myVariable = DocumentApp.openByUrl(newDocLink).getText();`.

Comment: This is a weird url... documents are normally like that : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KuedG8esz108_kF1mkYSJsXYFBLbCfhui9SO6eKLvWc/edit  which is quite different... where does it come from ? you couls use openById as well rather than this ?parameter structure.

Comment: Thanks for the observations. Now I update the code. I get the `url` with `.getUrl()` method?

Comment: it seems indeed it doesn't work this way... I suggest you use the Id instead, the url works only in a browser...

Comment: I just came here because I got the same `"Invalid argument: url"` error when trying to open a doc using `DocsList.openByUrl()` and I found out that passing in a goo.gl shortlink produces this error, while using a full Google Docs URL works. I know this won't help you but it might help someone else who ends up here when searching for this error message.

Answer (score 1):

newDocLink is never defined above where it is used as an argument.